# PostgreSQL: speed up SELECT query in table with millions of rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, select

I have a table with > 4.5 million rows and my `SELECT` query is far too slow for my needs.

The table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE all_legs (
                carrier TEXT,
                dep_hub TEXT,
                arr_hub TEXT,
                dep_dt TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
                arr_dt TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
                price_ct INTEGER,
                ... 5 more cols ...,
                PRIMARY KEY (carrier, dep_hub, arr_hub, dep_dt, arr_dt, ...3 other cols...)
                )
```

When I want to `SELECT` all rows for a certain date, the query is too slow; it takes between 12sec and 20 seconds. My aim is that it takes max 1 sec. I expect the query to return between 0.1% and 1% of the rows contained in the table.

The query is quite simple:

```
SELECT * FROM all_legs WHERE dep_dt::date = '2017-08-15' ORDER BY price_ct ASC
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns:

```
Sort  (cost=197154.69..197212.14 rows=22982 width=696) (actual time=14857.300..14890.565 rows=31074 loops=1)
  Sort Key: price_ct
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5256kB
  ->  Seq Scan on all_legs  (cost=0.00..188419.85 rows=22982 width=696) (actual time=196.738..14581.143 rows=31074 loops=1)
        Filter: ((dep_dt)::date = '2017-08-15'::date)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 4565249
Planning time: 0.572 ms
Execution time: 14908.274 ms
```

*Note: I learned yesterday about this command, so I am still not able to fully understand all that is returned.*

I have tried using `index-only scans`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13236089/5802289), by running the command: `CREATE index idx_all_legs on all_legs(dep_dt);` but I did not notice any difference in running time. I also tried creating the index for all columns, as I want all columns return.

Another thought was sorting all rows by `dep_dt`, so then the search of all rows fulfilling the condition should be much faster as they would not be scattered. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this.

Is there a way to make it as fast as I am aiming to?

---

## Solution

As suggested in the [Laurenz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321419/5802289), by adding an index `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_dep_dt_price ON all_legs(dep_dt, price_ct);` and adapting the condition in the `SELECT` to `WHERE dep_dt >= '2017-08-15 00:00:00' AND dep_dt < '2017-08-16 00:00:00'` has reduced the running time to 1/4. Even if it is a very good improvement, that means running times between 2 and 6 seconds.

Any additional idea to reduce the running time even further would be appreciated.

Comment: Vacuum your table also, this will make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've run `VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) all_legs;`, but it did not make any difference in my case.

Comment: Another thing that helps to make it faster is including some more restrictive conditions to the `SELECT` query, and of course, include those factors to the index.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The index won't help.

Two solutions:

1. You chould either change the query to:

   ```
   WHERE dep_dt >= '2017-08-15 00:00:00' AND dep_dt < '2017-08-16 00:00:00'
   ```

   Then the index can be used.
2. Create an index on an expression:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON all_legs(((dep_dt AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date));
   ```

   (or a different time zone) and change the query to

   ```
   WHERE (dep_dt AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date = '2017-08-16'
   ```

   The `AT TIME ZONE` is necessary because otherwise the result of the cast would depend on your current `TimeZone` setting.

The first solution is simpler, but the second has the advantage that you can add `price_ct` to the index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON all_legs(((dep_dt AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date), price_ct);
```

Then you don't need a sort any more, and your query will be as fast as it can theoretically get.

Comment: The first suggestion reduced the time by 50% more or less. Concerning the second suggestion, I receive the following error when trying to create the index: `ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Comment: The error is apparently because "The conversion of a timestamp with time zone to a date is not "immutable" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34293331/5802289)). However, by using the query on the first suggestion and creating an index on (dep_dt, price_ct) the query time is reduced to somewhere between 2 and 6 secs.

Answer (score 5):

The index does not help because you use

```
WHERE dept_dt::date=constant
```

This seems fine to a beginner, but to the database, it looks like:

```
WHERE convert_timestamp_to_date(dep_ts)=constant
```

With convert_timestamp_to_date() being an arbitrary function (I just came up with the name, don't look it up in the docs). In order to use the index on dep_ts, the DB would have to reverse the function convert_timestamp_to_date into something like convert_date_to_timestamp_range (because a date corresponds to a range of timestamps, not just one timestamp), and then rewrite the WHERE as Laurenz did.

Since there are many such functions, the database developers didn't bother to maintain a huge table of how to invert them. Also it would only help for special cases. For example, if you specified a date range in your WHERE instead of a "=constant" then it would be yet another special case. It's your job to handle this ;)

Also, an index on (dep_dt,price_ct) won't speed up the sort as the first column is a timestamp, so the rows are not ordered in the index the way you want. You'd need an index on (dept_dt::date, price_ct) to eliminate the sort.

Now, which index to create? This depends...

If you also use timestamp range queries like "WHERE dep_dt BETWEEN ... AND ..." then the index on dep_dt needs to be the original timestamp type. In this case, creating another index on the same column, but converted to date, would be unnecessary (all indexes have to be updated on writes, so unnecessary indexes slow down inserts/updates). However, if you use the index on (dep_ts::date,price_ct) lots and lots of times and eliminating the sort is really important for you, then it may make sense. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Speed for `SELECT` queries is critical, but if `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are slower, it would not be so important. As this query will be run many time, it seems to make sense to create an index on (dep_ts::date,price_ct). How would that query look like? As I wrote in the comments of Laurenz's answer, I got an error when I tried: `ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Answer (score 3):

1. The very first you should change here is to **remove composite** `primary key` and use plain one-column one instead of this. 
   This is because if you're going to use some columns index, it works the best with something like one column integer index which is here like a spine and allows your index to fetch fast rows you need to. When you have such big index like in your example, the planner may say that it will be faster for him to scan through whole table.
2. Even if your index would be good enough to be used by planner, it **may be dropped by ordering**. I say that 'may be' as - as many things in sql - it depends on your actuall data in table, analyses, and so on.
   I'm not sure about Postgres but you may want to try to build another index on column used in `order by` or even to try composite index for `(dep_dt, price_ct)`. Also you may try to put `dep_dt` to `order by` list to give a compiler a hint.
3. Do you need **all** from this table? Using `*` vs `id` (for example) can also have a impact here.
4. How unique values you have in `dep_dt` column? Sometimes planner can say that it may be more effective in making scan through whole table than by index because there is **many non-unique values** here.

In summary, **SQL querying is art of experimenting**, as it all depends on current data (as planner is using statistics build by analyzer to guess optimal query plan). So it may even happen that when you have tuned query to table with thousand of rows, it may stop working when you reach millions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Adam. Concerning point 1, I created that primary key to avoid duplicates. Would it make a difference if I switch from `PRIMARY KEY (carrier, dep_hub, arr_hub, dep_dt, arr_dt, ...3 other cols...)` to `UNIQUE (carrier, dep_hub, arr_hub, dep_dt, arr_dt, ...3 other cols...)`?

Comment: Yes, I believe it would be much better at the end of the day. Composite primary key is nothing good, at least in my experience. And yes, such `UNIQUE` could be enough.